# Java7 to Java8 - issue with Spacing between elements in Javafx Application

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

Java7 to Java8 - issue with UI, Spacing between elements in Javafx Application.

It's not duplicate issue as i already settled default skin.

When i run my application with Java7, It displays proper UI, with proper background color.
But when i run same application with Java8, It displayes UI differ than that of Java7.
Some elements overlapped for example button in GridPane, some spacing decreased between elements in GridPane and Background color not settled properly.

Currently, I have referenced CSS in FXML file but I tested after removing that. Still issue is there.

Please give solution, so that i can have a same UI for javafx application with Java7 as well as with Java8.

I tried to resolve by following two ways.
1. use System.setProperty( "javafx.userAgentStylesheetUrl", "CASPIAN" ) in stage method of controller.
2.  run with -Djavafx.userAgentStylesheetUrl=caspian on the command line.

Here is the code of Sample 
**t1.fxml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <center>
      <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <StackPane prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0">
               <children>
                  <HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                         <GridPane maxHeight="285.0" maxWidth="285.0" minHeight="286.0" minWidth="200.0" prefHeight="286.0" prefWidth="278.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                            <columnConstraints>
                              <ColumnConstraints halignment="LEFT" hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="110.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="50.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints halignment="LEFT" hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="110.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="50.0" />
                                <ColumnConstraints halignment="LEFT" hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="110.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="50.0" />
                                <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="162.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                            </columnConstraints>
                            <rowConstraints>
                              <RowConstraints maxHeight="36.0" minHeight="10.0" percentHeight="5.0" prefHeight="26.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints maxHeight="66.0" minHeight="10.0" percentHeight="19.0" prefHeight="66.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints maxHeight="66.0" minHeight="10.0" percentHeight="19.0" prefHeight="66.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                <RowConstraints maxHeight="66.0" minHeight="10.0" percentHeight="19.0" prefHeight="66.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                <RowConstraints maxHeight="55.0" minHeight="10.0" percentHeight="19.0" prefHeight="55.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                <RowConstraints maxHeight="55.0" minHeight="10.0" percentHeight="19.0" prefHeight="55.0" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                            </rowConstraints>
                             <children>
                                <BorderPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                                 <center>
                                    <Button maxHeight="50.0" maxWidth="105.0" minHeight="50.0" minWidth="105.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="105.0" styleClass="keyButton" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
                                 </center></BorderPane>
                              <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                              <Button contentDisplay="CENTER" maxHeight="50.0" maxWidth="50.0" minHeight="50.0" minWidth="50.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="50.0" styleClass="keyButton" text="7" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                              <Button maxHeight="50.0" maxWidth="50.0" minHeight="50.0" minWidth="50.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="50.0" styleClass="keyButton" text="8" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                              <Button maxHeight="50.0" maxWidth="50.0" minHeight="50.0" minWidth="50.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="50.0" styleClass="keyButton" text="9" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                              <Button maxHeight="50.0" maxWidth="50.0" minHeight="50.0" minWidth="50.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="50.0" styleClass="keyButton" text="4" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                              <Button maxHeight="50.0" maxWidth="50.0" minHeight="50.0" minWidth="50.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="50.0" styleClass="keyButton" text="5" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                              <Button maxHeight="50.0" maxWidth="50.0" minHeight="50.0" minWidth="50.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="50.0" styleClass="keyButton" text="6" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                              <Button maxHeight="50.0" maxWidth="50.0" minHeight="50.0" minWidth="50.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="50.0" styleClass="keyButton" text="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
                              <Button maxHeight="50.0" maxWidth="50.0" minHeight="50.0" minWidth="50.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="50.0" styleClass="keyButton" text="2" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
                              <Button maxHeight="50.0" maxWidth="50.0" minHeight="50.0" minWidth="50.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="50.0" styleClass="keyButton" text="3" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
                              <Button maxHeight="50.0" maxWidth="105.0" minHeight="50.0" minWidth="105.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="105.0" styleClass="keyButton" text="0" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
                              <Button maxHeight="50.0" maxWidth="50.0" minHeight="50.0" minWidth="50.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="50.0" styleClass="keyButton" text="," GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
                              <Button maxHeight="50.0" maxWidth="105.0" minHeight="50.0" minWidth="105.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="105.0" styleClass="keyButton" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                              <Button maxHeight="104.0" maxWidth="105.0" minHeight="104.0" minWidth="105.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="104.0" prefWidth="105.0" styleClass="keyButton" text="Enter" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="4" GridPane.rowSpan="2147483647" />
                              <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                             </children>
                          </GridPane>
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
               </children>
            </StackPane>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </center>

</BorderPane>
```

**Style.css**

```
.keyButton{
    -fx-font:bold 18px "Arial";
    -fx-background-color: rgb(240,240,240);
    -fx-border-radius: 10;
    -fx-background-radius:10;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
    -fx-border-color:rgb(206,206,206);
}
.keyButton:pressed{    
    -fx-background-color:rgb(217,217,217);
}
```

**MainApp.java**

```
public class MainApp extends Application {

     @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
          Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/t1.fxml"));

            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            scene.getStylesheets().add("/style/Style.css");
            System.setProperty( "javafx.userAgentStylesheetUrl", "CASPIAN" );
            stage.setTitle("JavaFX and Maven");
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();


        }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }


}
```

I Run the Application with -Djavafx.userAgentStylesheetUrl=caspian argument

View Of this XML Differs in Java7 & Java8 As shown in below linked images

Java7
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fURv.png

Java8
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejBAy.png

Comment: Please provide the FXML and CSS you use to produce your layout.

Comment: Hi @BenjaminGale, I updated question and added FXML & CSS with the question.